# Differentiate between IPFS link and normal link

Tags: python-3.x, ipfs

I have a functionality where I have to differentiate between an IPFS link and a video streaming link.
If it is an IPFS link I have to download and save and use that to show video else just show video using streaming link.

```
     if "https" in url or "http" in url:
            return url 
     else:
            #store and return the stored path
```

currently I am trying something like this is this valid or is there any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect HTTP(S) URLs that include IPFS Identifiers (content-addressed),  you could re-implement URL detection from JS util: [is-ipfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ipfs).